# VUID-VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT-messageType-parameter error in Vulkan using valid flag bits for vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT

Tags: rust, vulkan

I'm using the vulkanalia crate for Rust, following [this](https://kylemayes.github.io/vulkanalia/setup/validation_layers.html) tutorial.
There is this assignment near the end of the `create_instance` function:

```
let mut debug_info = vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT::builder()
    .message_severity(vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagsEXT::all())
    .message_type(vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT::all())
    .user_callback(Some(debug_callback));
```

However, running the code in the tutorial I get the following validation error:

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT-messageType-parameter ] 
Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xdf09e3a0 | 
VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT: value of messageType contains flag bits that are not recognized members of VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT 
The Vulkan spec states: messageType must be a valid combination of VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT values (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT-messageType-parameter)
```

By replacing `vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT::all()` with specific bitsets, I find that the problem is the bitset `8`, corresponding to the `DEVICE_ADDRESS_BINDING` flag.

Why is Vulkan not recognizing this flag?

Answer (score 0):

Because `DEVICE_ADDRESS_BINDING` is from an extension that you have not enabled.

In Vulkan you can only use functionality from extensions which you have enabled.

[VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BINDING_BIT_EXT](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap49.html#VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230610194504/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap49.html#VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagBitsEXT)</sub> is defined in the device extension [VK_EXT_device_address_binding_report](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap54.html#VK_EXT_device_address_binding_report) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230610194605/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap54.html#VK_EXT_device_address_binding_report)</sub>

Its specific purpose is to

> specify that the implementation has modified the set of GPU-visible virtual addresses associated with a Vulkan object.

You can technically ignore the warning, it's unlikely that having an extra flag set will cause problems with the loader or ICD, but strictly speaking it is a violation of the spec to have invalid flags set.

If you don't need the functionality of that extension you should probably just limit the enabled message types to only the valid bits, rather than enabling an unnecessary extension.